# To suppress the output of snmpwalk command when it gives timeout response

Tags: unix

I have written a script to automate the `snmpwalk` command for a given community string and IP addresses. I am storing the result as "yes" if it is alive, and "no" otherwise.

But the problem is for IP's which are not connected. It is showing timeout response on the console.

How can I suppress this message ?

Comment: You can use the redirect to null, to suppress error output. Example : http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html - use **2> /dev/null**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the redirect to null, to suppress error output.
Example : [All about redirection](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) - use **2> /dev/null** –  tvCa